# Two dimensional array of class and the constructor call in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a problem in which I have a class, and I need a two-dimensional array of that class. Normally I would do this using vectors, but unfortunately I am working with a library where this is not really possible, which lead to me realizing how little I know about conventional C arrays.

I did some research on this topic and found many answers on how to properly make a two-dimensional array in c++, and even two-dimensional arrays for classes. The problem was only that all solutions ommited the calling of the constructor, something which i need. Take the following example:

```
class cClass
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    cClass()
    {
    }
};

int main(int argv, char argc[])
{
    cClass ** cClass_testClass = new cClass*[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cClass_testClass[i] = new cClass[5];
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

To my understanding, this creates a two-dimensional 5x5 array of the class 'cCLass'. And it'll work because the constructor doesn't really do anything. Now say I would rather have the x and y values in the class to correspond to the x and y values in the array, and I for some reason could only do this in the constructor itself, how would I approach this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you're allocating memory, and never releasing it - each new[] should be matched by a delete[], i.e. `delete [] cClass_testClass[i]` for each `i`, and `delete [] cClass_testClass` to delete the arrays' array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to do an array of class `cClass`, you'll need it to have a constructor with no parameters, and that's the constructor that will be called upon allocation of the array (`new cClass[5]`).

To solve your problem, create a two-dimensional array of *pointers* to cClass:

```
cClass*** cClass_testClass = new cClass**[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    cClass_testClass[i] = new cClass*[5];
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        cClass_testClass[i][j] = new cClass(i, j);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to eventually `delete` all the dynamically allocated memory!